# Most general solution of an ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider $y''(x)=0$. It seems obvious that the most general solution to this equation is given by $y=Ax+B$, where $A, B \in \mathbb{R}$, which can be confirmed through integration. But how do we know that this is indeed the most general solution to this equation, and that no other had been omitted? I know there are ODE's where some solution may be omitted when standard methods are used, e.g the trivial division by zero, so how do we know if a solution to an ODE is the most general one?

Comment: "..... which can be confirmed through integration. But how do we know that this is indeed the most general solution to this equation?" THE ANSWER IS IN YOUR QUESTION: "can be confirmed through integration"

Comment: Maybe this can also be answered by considering the basis of the vector space which consists of all the solutions of the class of ODE

Comment: Do you have an example where it is not obvious that integration gives the general solution? For linear ODEs with constant coefficients you can express all possible solutions with the matrix exponential function. This is general. For your example you have $A=[0,1;0,0]$ and two eigenvalues at $0$. This yields the same solution as integration

Answer (score 3):

The answer is right in your question. Integration is the straight-forward way to prove it.

Assuming $y''(x) = 0$ as a differential equation over the real variable $x$ :

$$y''(x) = 0 \Rightarrow \int y''(x)dx =\int0dx\Rightarrow y'(x) = A \Rightarrow\int y'(x)dx = \int Adx \Rightarrow$$

$$\Rightarrow$$

$$y(x) = Ax + B \space , \space \text{where} \space A,B \space \text{constants} \space \in \mathbb R$$

Answer (score 3):

If a function's derivative is zero, then the function is constant; this is an essential point regarding integration. So you know that $y'(x)=A$ for some constant $A$. Now consider $z(x)=Ax$. Then 
$$
(z-y)'=z'-y'=A-A=0. 
$$
So $y(x)-z(x)=B$ for some constant $B$. That is, $y(x)=Ax+B$.

In general, for some nice enough differential equations one can prove *existence and uniqueness results*. So, for instance, for a second order linear, homogeneous, constant coefficient equation, one can prove that there is a unique solution provided that the value of the function and its derivative are prescribed at a single point. Then, if you find a solution to the initial value problem, you will know its the only one because of the theorem.

Comment: When the right hand side of the corresponding first order system of odes satisfies a Lipschitz condition uniqueness should be given (?) which is obviously fulfilled here.